# Fetch user DOB & gender using Google People API iOS

Tags: ios, swift, google-people-api

I have read multiple articles online but couldn't find proper documentation/steps to integrate Google People API in iOS app.

```
GTLRPeopleServiceQuery_PeopleGet *getDataQuery = 
[GTLRPeopleServiceQuery_PeopleGet queryWithResourceName: @"people/me"];
    [getDataQuery setPersonFields:@"genders,birthdays"];        

    GTLRPeopleServiceService *gService = [[GTLRPeopleServiceService alloc] init];
    [gService setAPIKey:@"APIKEYHERE"];
    [gService executeQuery: getDataQuery delegate:self didFinishSelector:@selector(getCreatorFromTicket:finishedWithObject:error:)];


-(void)getCreatorFromTicket:(GTLRServiceTicket *) ticket finishedWithObject: (GTLRPeopleService_Person *) finishedWithObject error: (NSError *)error
{
if (error != nil) {
    NSLog(@"Error is %@", error.localizedDescription);
}

NSLog(@"Response is %@", finishedWithObject);
}
```

I am getting below error

```
The request does not have valid authentication credentials.
```

Can any one tell me, how to add auth credentials or how to fix this issue ?

I want to fetch User's Gender & date of birth

Answer (score 0):

You need to authenticate the user using OAuth.

I'm not an iOS engineer, but you should look at one of the Google Objective-C client code [examples], such as the [StorageExample StorageSampleWindowController.m](https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client-for-rest/blob/master/Examples/StorageSample/StorageSampleWindowController.m). You will need to use code similar to the `runSigninThenHandler` function that makes an authorization request, and then sets the authorizer on the service.

Answer (score 0):

The authenticated user object of type GIDGoogleUser should be send as param to GTLRPeopleServiceService.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) GIDGoogleUser *googleUserObject;

-(void)fetchGoogleUserInfo{
    GTLRPeopleServiceQuery_PeopleGet *getDataQuery = [GTLRPeopleServiceQuery_PeopleGet queryWithResourceName: @"people/me"];
    [getDataQuery setPersonFields:@"birthdays,genders"];    
    GTLRPeopleServiceService *gService = [[GTLRPeopleServiceService alloc] init];
    gService.authorizer = [[self.googleUserObject authentication] fetcherAuthorizer];
    [gService executeQuery: getDataQuery delegate:self didFinishSelector:@selector(getCreatorFromTicket:finishedWithObject:error:)];
}


-(void)getCreatorFromTicket:(GTLRServiceTicket *) ticket finishedWithObject: (GTLRPeopleService_Person *) finishedWithObject error: (NSError *)error{
    if (error != nil) {
        DLog(@"Error is %@", error.localizedDescription);
    }
}
```